# Spring ResponsEntity Return

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jhipster

I am using JHipster. I want to display some data on my webpage. i have a `ResponseEntity` method . where i can print the data with `forEach(System.out::println)`

Now the problem is System.out.println is a void. if use the code

```
 return  new ResponseEntity(a.map(b::collectinfo)
.forEach(System.out::println), HttpStatus.OK);
```

it says

> Error:(99, 77) java: 'void' type not allowed here

The post method has been used

how can i fix this.

Comment: Use some buffer and print into it?

Comment: If you just want to see what's inside the stream without terminating it, you could use [peek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-). Note that you still need to collect the result of your stream.

Comment: instead of using above code using this
return new ResponseEntity(collection, HttpStatus.OK);
Later in the client code you  iterate this collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably stream the list(If the output of `b::collectinfo` is a list), use peek to display values and collect it back to the list(If the output of `b::collectinfo` is a list).

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
return new ResponseEntity(list.stream().peek(System.out::println).collect(Collectors.toList()), HttpStatus.OK);
```

For your code (Change your collect method according to your `b::collectinfo` output):

```
return  new ResponseEntity(a.map(b::collectinfo)
.stream().peek(System.out::println).collect(Collectors.toList()), HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: The problem is i am getting the output in the console. but in broswer its

Object {data: "", status: 406, config: Object, statusText: "Not Acceptable"}

Comment: and the a is a Stream<Header>

Comment: What is the value of `Accept` in the Headers that client is sending?

Comment: 406 the header status

Comment: No, I mean [http headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) list what is the value of header `Accept` that the client has passed. 406 occurs because the Content Type that is acceptable by client is not the same that server is sending. Is the Stream<Header> converted to say a json or string type?

Comment: i am sorry... this is my @RequestMapping(value = "/link",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)

Comment: the browser` Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*`

Comment: hmm, I guess that's the issue. Have you written any object converters to convert this Stream<Header> Object to PLAIN_TEXT? If not, you can change the `produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN` to `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`. So the object can be converted to json and sent to client.